# Print one line or resize page before print with html2canvas

Tags: jquery, printing, html2canvas

I have a Point of sale printer (POS 58mm) and Kiosk Mode on Chrome.
I want to print the html below, but my printer it's printig a lot of paper.

It's possible to print only one line or resize page before print???

```
<div id="openBox" class="hidden">
  <div class="row" style="color: #fff;">
    <span>*</span>
  </div>
</div>


$('#openBox').removeClass('hidden');
    html2canvas($('#openBox'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var tWindow = window.open(''); 
            $(tWindow.document.body).html("<img id='Image' src=" + myImage + " ></img>").ready(function () {
                tWindow.focus();
                tWindow.print();
                tWindow.close();
            });
         }
     });
$('#openBox').addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Anybody can answer this?